# SPSR is changing modes but not able to change the CPSR mode in armv7

Tags: assembly, arm

I am trying to change the modes of my processor. I have tried the following code and I am able to change the SPSR mode to monitor mode.

```
mov r0, #0x16;  
msr SPSR, r0;
```

But while I tried the same code with the CPSR. I didn't get any change from the default mode which is the supervisor mode.

```
mov r0, #0x16;  
msr CPSR, r0;
```

Then I tried the following code and I am able to change the SPSR mode to user mode.

```
mov r0,#0x10;  
msr SPSR, r0;
```

But while I tried the same code with the CPSR.I didn't get any change from the default mode which is the supervisor mode.

```
mov r0, #0x10;  
msr CPSR, r0;
```

I was expecting the msr instruction to work any of the status registers. Can any one give explanation for this behavior. And the right strategy to  change the modes of CPSR.

Comment: Normally you use `CPS` to change modes.  Changing modes depends a lot on context (dual meaning here).  What CPU do you have and what mode you are in and why you want to change the context.  There are already different examples (Q/A) [on this issue here at stackoverflow under the ARM tag](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Barm%5D+CPS).

Comment: I have seen different SO links on this aspect. My CPSR is in supervisor mode. I have tried CPS #0x16; also to change from the supervisor to monitor mode. It didn't have any effect.

Comment: Does your CPU have TrustZone? Are you in the normal or secure world?

Comment: I am in secure world

Comment: let me guess are you in hyp mode?  it is a bit if a pain to switch out of hyp mode.  and as already asked, then why do you want to change modes.  better chance of just booting the processor into your code rather than trying to undo someone elses boot code

Comment: I want to verify that mode switches are happening properly and warnings are executed when some invalid mode switch happens.

Comment: hmm, I cant remember, it may simply ignore the write, that or it causes an exception...easy to setup all the handlers to trap which one fires if any.